# Vagrant 2.2.3 error : Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot

Tags: vagrant

### environment:

windows 10 1809 x64
[Vagrant 2.2.3](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)
[centos/7 v1901.01](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7)
[VirtualBox 6.0.4](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

### Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos7"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.3"
  config.vm.synced_folder "d:/workspace/www/", "/var/www"  

  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-dev"


  config.ssh.username = 'root'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus = 2
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end
end
```

### error:

```
λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: root
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config

```
# Automatically installs required plugin on Windows
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
  plugin = 'vagrant-winnfsd'

  system "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin?(plugin)
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # Sync the sources folder with the machine
  # For Windows `nfs` is preferred due to poor performance of default settings.
  if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder "share", "/var/www/html", type: 'nfs'
  else
    config.vm.synced_folder "share", "/var/www/html", mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]
  end
end
```